# Pt displays larger in TextView than WebView

Tags: android, css, textview, android-webview, font-size

My app uses both `TextView`s and `WebView`s. In both I set the size of text in `pt`. The problem is that the text in `WebView` is usually half the size as the text in `TextView`. I have tested on multiple screen sizes and desnsities but it makes no difference.

I set `TextView` height using:

`textView.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 14 );`

But in `WebView` I use CSS:

`font: 14pt;`

Both work, but it seems like `TextView`'s display is bigger than `WebView`'s. Any clue what is going on? I want to display the text in `TextView` as the same size as in my `WebView`.

Comment: Since `WebView` zooms, I would presume `WebView` is at fault. Since a `pt` is supposed to be 1/72nd of an inch, do either `TextView` or `WebView` give you something that is approximately the right size?

Comment: I believe the `WebView` gives the appropriate size. I have never directly done anything with `WebView`'s zoom, so not sure either way what could be going on there.